# Java cross thread / cross object Map sharing + generics

Tags: java, multithreading, generics, shared

Good evening Java wizards,

I am fairly new to Java, and would like to be educated on the mistake I am not able to resolve after some hours of research.

Assume a program that has the main thread with some variables that could dynamically read/lookup value in a Map of values. This Map is shared by threads and objects accross the application.

There would be one or more separate threads updating the Map with values thus the map will be synchronized - I am considering ConcurrentHashMap.

When the reading thread arrives to one of the variables with the dynamic values it will reach in to the cross-thread shared Map and retreive its latest value against its key.

I have some prototype code here - it compliles and seam to be running as expected. However it is set to work only with a String variable and values.

Here is the code:

```
<code>

/*
 * Cross thread / cross object shared Map
 * some threads update the map
 * other threads read the map for most current values (updated by other threads)
 * associated with the provided key
 */
public class CrossThreadUpdatableValues {

    private static final Map<Integer, String> list = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    // return the last updated value
    // from the map
    public static String getValue(Integer key) {
        return list.get(key);
    }

    // update/write the passed in value in to the map
    // (in to the element having the given key)
    public static void setValue(Integer key, String ev) {
        list.put(key, ev);
    }
}



/*
 * Thread 1
 * 10 loops that update the cross thread / cross object shared Map
 * with unique values
 */
public class Thread1 extends Thread {

    private final int delay;
    private final int threadNum = 1;

    Thread1(int delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
    }

    public void run(){

        for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {

            String v1 = threadNum + "-AAA"; Integer key1 = 1;
            String v2 = threadNum + "-BBB"; Integer key2 = 2;
            String v3 = threadNum + "-CCC"; Integer key3 = 3;

            CrossThreadUpdatableValues.setValue(key1, v1);
            CrossThreadUpdatableValues.setValue(key2, v2);
            CrossThreadUpdatableValues.setValue(key3, v3);

            System.out.println("Map values updated by Thread " + threadNum + ", loop " + i);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(this.delay);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Thread2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}



/*
 * Thread 2 (similar to Thread 1)
 * 10 loops that update the cross thread / cross object shared Map
 * with unique values
 */

public class Thread2 extends Thread {

    private final int delay;
    private final int threadNum = 2;

    Thread2(int delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
    }

    public void run(){

        for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {

            String v1 = threadNum + "-XXX"; Integer key1 = 1;
            String v2 = threadNum + "-YYY"; Integer key2 = 2;
            String v3 = threadNum + "-ZZZ"; Integer key3 = 3;

            CrossThreadUpdatableValues.setValue(key1, v1);
            CrossThreadUpdatableValues.setValue(key2, v2);
            CrossThreadUpdatableValues.setValue(key3, v3);

            System.out.println("Map values updated by Thread " + threadNum + ", loop " + i);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(this.delay);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Thread2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Reading thread -
 * 20 loops that read the cross thread / crooss object shared Map
 * for the most current values updated by other threads in various intervals
 */
public class ThreadRead extends Thread {

    private final int delay;
    private final int threadNum = 0;

    ThreadRead(int delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
    }

    public void run(){

        Integer key1 = 1;
        Integer key2 = 2;
        Integer key3 = 3;

        for (int i=0;i<20;i++) {

            String v1 = CrossThreadUpdatableValues.getValue(key1);
            String v2 = CrossThreadUpdatableValues.getValue(key1);
            String v3 = CrossThreadUpdatableValues.getValue(key1);

            System.out.println(" - - - Map values read by (reading) thread " + threadNum + ", loop " + i + "; v1 = " + v2 + "; v1 = " + v2 + "; v3 = " + v3);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(this.delay);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Thread2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 *
 * Main test class - start of test run
 */
public class Test_Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // start thread that populates the shared Map with unique values
    // in 5 second intervals (10x)
    Thread1 thread1 = new Thread1(5000);
    thread1.start();

    // start thread that populates the shared Map with unique values
    // in 10 second intervals (10x)
    Thread2 thread2 = new Thread2(10000);
    thread2.start();

    // start thread that reads the shared Map of unique values
    // - the latest updates from any previous thread
    // in 5 second intervals (20x)
    ThreadRead threadRead = new ThreadRead(5000);
    threadRead.start();

  }
}
</code>
```

These dynamic variables will naturally be of different types (Integers, Strings, etc.), so I am considering using generics, BUT that gives me the uneducated headache. As the Map needs to be shared between all involved classes and threads, it needs to be declared static and Java won't permit the use of generics on this static Map.

Here is the modification of above class CrossThreadUpdatableValues using generics - that will NOT work but a hint what I am trying to achieve:

```
<code>

/*
 * Cross thread / crooss object shared Map
 * some threads update the map
 * other threads read the map for most current values (udated by other threads)
 * associated with the provided key
 */
public class CrossThreadUpdatableValues<K, V> {

    private static final Map<K, V> list = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    // return the last updated value
    // from the map
    public static V getValue(K key) {
        return list.get(key);
    }


    // update/write the passed in value in to the map
    // (in to the element having the given key)
    public static void setValue(K key, V v) {
        list.put(key, v);
    }
}

</code>
```

I would appreciate your input into how to approach this in a thread save manner, allow handling various types of variables (I know Object could be used instead of V but is it the right way to go?) and perhaps point out some hints or references on a solution or a better approach.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save different types in the Map you will need to use Object, using generics will force a design where a specific map is created for each combination of `<K, V>`.

Comment: Appreciated Holadola, I thought this would be the easiest way, but wanted to get some feedback from the experienced. Thx,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store in the same map differents kind of objects, you don´t need generics, declare your map as

```
Map <String, Object>
```

Otherwise, you can use an interface like this

```
package a;

public interface ICrossThreadUpdatableValues<K, V> {

    // return the last updated value
    // from the map
    V getValue(K key);

    // update/write the passed in value in to the map
    // (in to the element having the given key)
    void setValue(K key, V v);
}
```

And then do a concrete implementation for the desired types like this

```
package a;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

/*
 * Cross thread / crooss object shared Map
 * some threads update the map
 * other threads read the map for most current values (udated by other threads)
 * associated with the provided key
 */
public class IntegerCrossThreadUpdatableValues implements ICrossThreadUpdatableValues<String, Integer> {

    private final Map<String, Integer> list = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private static IntegerCrossThreadUpdatableValues instance;

    private IntegerCrossThreadUpdatableValues() {

    }

    // return the last updated value
    // from the map
    public Integer getValue(String key) {
        return list.get(key);
    }

    // update/write the passed in value in to the map
    // (in to the element having the given key)
    public void setValue(String key, Integer v) {
        list.put(key, v);
    }

    public static IntegerCrossThreadUpdatableValues getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new IntegerCrossThreadUpdatableValues();
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Note that the implementation defines a singleton pattern, you can´t instantiate the class outside of it and you can get always the same object calling 'getInstance'

Comment: Thank you Francisco, I'll play with this idea, to learn a bit more about the instance approach. I am wandering if the updates from other threads will persist in the map with the instantiation approach, but it should as the getInstance allows for only 1 instance. I'll let you know if any issues pop up. Thx again.